# Information regarding salesforce

Tags: c#, asp.net, salesforce

I am developing an application in ASP.NET and in that I need to integrate sales force CRM using APEX. Like I have reach a bit over that, I need to write the APEX code on salesforce devlopers area and need to call tha functions and classes from my ASP.NET application, buti am not sure that i am following the right way. So can any one please help me how can I integrate APEX (Salesforce) in to my ASP.NET C# application. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Doing things "the right way" is highly subjective and will vary greatly depending on your specific requirements.

Generally speaking, if you want to invoke Apex from .NET there are two ways to do so:

1. Expose a static Apex method as a web service. This is as easy as making the Apex class global, adding the `webService` keyword to the static method, and then finally generating the WSDL in Salesforce that can be imported into .NET. See [WebService Methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_web_services_methods.htm).
2. If you aren't interested in getting any data back you could also run anonymous Apex via the [Apex API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex/Content/apex_api.htm). This is less commonly used, so you would be better sticking with a SOAP or REST web service.

See also [Invoking Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_invoking.htm)

When you import the apex webservice WSDL into your .NET project you will get a service class generated. Create an instance of this and then create a `SessionHeader` for it's `SessionHeaderValue`. This `SessionHeader` will require the ServerURL and SessionId to be set. Assign your access token to the SessionId here. Then you should be free to call your web service. See [Calling a custom Salesforce Apex web service from C#](http://whiterabbitservices.com/2011/04/01/calling-a-custom-salesforce-apex-web-service-from-c/)

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I have created a demo class in that for checking that record is inserting or not on salesforce developer console and finally I am able to create a WSDL from that demo class. So now how can I call that class from ASP.NET like we have two method for that Auth 2.0 and password, I want to implement using Auth 2.0, so is there any inbuild class for Authenticating the user with salesforce if I am already have refresh token and access token.

Comment: I've added some more guidance on consuming the webservice.